# How login to microsoft account using cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using cypress for automation testing in my application. I have to login to the app using microsoft account. How can I write a testcase for this? I wrote testcase like this.

```
 cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/login')
 cy.get('.login-button-wrapper img').click({force:true});
```

It is working.. it should navigate page to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize? page. But is not loading... Please help me with this

Comment: you can not login into any server by using localhost, do not waste time because i have already did !!! you will find tutorials but policies are change now.

Comment: @SaadSohail  what tutorials?? I didn't get you. how you solved this case?

Comment: @RajithaKothapally Hi, Assuming that on clicking the button it should navigate to the mentioned URL. Mind adding wait after the click and then asserting the url. `cy.wait(5000); cy.url().should('include', 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize')`

Comment: @AlapanDas Page is redirecting to the mentioned Url. But I want  to login to the application. it showing as empty page.

Comment: @AlapanDas  using `wait` is a bad practice. Instead use `wait until`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until

Comment: @RajithaKothapally i mean you cannot login with localhost anymore to facebook, google etc

Comment: @SaadSohail Is there a way solve this problem?

Comment: use authenticate server !!!

Comment: `npm run ui:start // to start the UI`,
`npm run cypress:open // to start the cypress test window`,
`npm run mock:api // to start the mock server`,

we don't need to authenticate,by running above three commands parallely. Prevously I  have missed the third command.